# How do I input a new login?

Tags: login

When i got to the part of the installation where i type in a username, i chose one that was already selected and don't know how to create a new login, I've tried '''sudo -n [name]''' but then I don't know where to go from there

Comment: Are your trying to create a new user on your installed Ubuntu system, so you can select the new user on the login screen?

Answer (score 0):

Let's say you want to add a user called rtfm
Open a terminal and type `sudo adduser rtfm`
The system will prmpt you for a password. This is Linux so it won't display the text and you have to enter it blind twice for it to be accepted
Follow the prompts, then test, then report back to us.
It is of course much easier to do it via the GUI method and go to Settings then go to Users then click the big green Add Users button.